# Calculating the acceleration in a multiple pulley system with one mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

This sounded really simple to me at first, but how would you calculate acceleration within a multiple pulley system like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKZp7ziaJ7c&t=28m17s?) .

I understand that $5T = mg \implies T = \frac{mg}{5}$, but what if $F = 240~\text{ N}$ ? $F = T$ , right? so $T = 240~\text{N}$ ? But what if $m = 110~\text{kg}$ , and $mg = 1078~\text{N}$ so by doing $$T = \frac {mg}{5} \implies T = \frac{1078}{5} = 215.6~\text{N}$$.

So, $5T = 1078$, and $mg = 1078$. By using: $a = \frac{5T - mg}{m}$, you would get 0 in the numerator... so what am I not understanding?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]. _Your_ question is not very clear. Try to organize your thoughts in a sequence from what is known to what you have trouble understanding. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and also try to format your question using math formatting with `$...$`.

Comment: If $a=0$ then the system is not accelerating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tension is only equal to the $mg/5$ when the mass $m$ is not accelerating and thus the sum of all forces acting on it add up to zero. In the initial problem the force $F$ is unknown and the acceleration is known, namely zero. When the acceleration is not known but the force is, you can still use a previous relation you mentioned, namely $T=F$.

I do have to note that for this I am assuming that the mass of the rope and the moment of inertia of all pulleys can be neglected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if we knew that $F = 240 N$, then would this be correct? $T = 240 N$, then $5T = 1200 N$, so $(5T - mg)/m = a$ would be equal to $(1200 N - 1078 N) / 110 kg = 1.11 m/s^2$?

Comment: @Kawaiiii Yes, that is correct.